# Python, how to minus time using datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried the following, but get a type error

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'

```
import datetime
time1 = datetime.datetime.now().time()
time2 = datetime.datetime.now().time()
time3 = time2 - time1
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `.time()`:

```py
import datetime
time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
time2 = datetime.datetime.now()
time3 = time2 - time1
```

Comment: To be clearer with naming I would say use datetime1 and datetime2, and then time3 would be datetime3.time() or (datetime2 - datetime1).time()